# Linux : mail multiple files returned from grep

Tags: linux, file, email, grep

I want to grep for ora- errors in the log file.

```
grep  -L ora- *.log
```

suppose it returns abc.log and xyz.log

Then, I want to cat content of each file and mail it dynamically 
(like `cat abc.log|mail -s abc.log  myemail@email.com`)

For the above example ,  i am expecting tow emails with the contents of abc.log and xyz.log

I have tried  doing
 `grep -i -L ora- *.log|xargs cat| mail myemail@email.com` but it only send 1 email.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you loop through the files? `for file in $(grep -L ora- ...); do cat $file ... done`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just so that i know is it also possible to do using find -exec or xargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one mail per file, you need to loop or run `mail` as a child of `xargs`:

```
grep -L ora- *.log | xargs -i mailx -s "{}" -a "{}" myemail@email.com
```

If you want to attach all files to a single mail, then you would have to build a command:

```
cmd="mailx -s logs "
for f in $(grep  -L ora- *.log) ; do
    cmd="$cmd -a '$f'"
done

eval $cmd myemail@email.com
```

Note that this is brittle and breaks when file names contain single ticks.

Comment: How to run mail as child of xargs?  I am getting mail: invalid option -- a

Comment: Sorry, `mail` doesn't support attachments. Use `mailx` instead.